# Changing data for selected D3 object

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to change the x value in the data variable for my line object while I'm changing the x1 and x2 attributes. How do I do that? See code and image below.

```
function updateBorder(x, whichBorder) {
    temp_border = svg.selectAll(whichBorder)
    .attr("x1", x)
    .attr("x2", x);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your data in d3 callbacks.

```
function updateBorder(x, whichBorder) {
    temp_border = svg.selectAll(whichBorder)
    .each(function (d) { d.x = x })
    .attr("x1", x)
    .attr("x2", x);
}
```

But mutating data in random places not always good idea.